# I get message from client with python but there is no message on server with python?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, avro

when I write this code and run it on my desktop it works.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('ersin_test',
                         group_id='eg61-group',
                         auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                         enable_auto_commit=False,
                         consumer_timeout_ms=10000,
                         bootstrap_servers=['10.1.2.3:9092'])

for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

but when I move this code to different machine (server) it does not get any messages from kafka.
I run this code like this : `python my_script.py`

my server has connect kafka  server :

```
telnet 10.1.2.3 9092


Trying 10.1.2.3...
Connected to 10.1.2.3.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

**when I run this code on server it works and gets topic-names from kafka**

```
import kafka
consumer = kafka.KafkaConsumer(group_id='eg61-group',bootstrap_servers=['10.1.2.3:9092'])
t=consumer.topics()
print(t)

{'ersin_test', 'second-topic', 'abc', 'ESB', 'first-topic', 'ersin-topic'}
```

So what is the problem I cant understand.

how can I solve this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Install `kafkacat` and update your question to include the output of `kafkacat -b 10.1.2.3:9092 -L`

Comment: I dont have it and do not permission to install it

Comment: what is your Kafka broker configuration for `advertised.listeners` ?

Comment: `listeners=PLAINTEXT://myname:9092`

Comment: what's `myname` represent? Is it `10.1.2.3`?

Comment: yes ping myname is = 10.1.2.3

Comment: From your server, can it resolve `myname`? or only the IP?

Comment: you are right i cant ping myname I ping myname.co.intra so I write this name to `connect-avro-distributed.properties` but connect gives error like **Error connecting to node myname:9092** but I give this to bootstrap : myname.co.intra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The broker has `advertised.listeners` set to `myname`, but this DNS hostname is not resolvable from your client machine. 
This means that whilst the initial bootstrap connection to the IP address succeeds, the broker returns `myname` as the hostname on which the client should issue consume/produce requests, and since the client cannot resolve `myname` it fails.

You should fix your DNS so that you client machine can correctly resolve `myname`. If that's not an option then reconfigure your Kafka broker to set the `advertised.listeners` to the IP address (i.e. `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.1.2.3:9092`)

Ref: https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/